# How to add example json object to swagger body using java jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, swagger-ui

@ApiModelProperty(value = "Get Data", example= "{\"Happy\"}",required = true)
That is the thing i am trying to add but it doesn't show any change.
And the output is not as i expected.

I even tried by using @ApiParam in function definition. Even then it is not working.

Comment: Welcome SO. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)